# Making a db conn global

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have made a db connection to fetch from data in the code and now i need to keep this Db instance global and need to use in the other parts of the project.

Please guide me on the same.

I have the below code

```
try
    {   
        // load the DB2 Driver
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        // establish a connection to DB2
        Connection db2Conn = DriverManager.getConnection
        (dbUrl,"wcsadm",dbPass);
        // use a statement to gather data from the database
        Statement st = db2Conn.createStatement();
        String myQuery=null;
        String insQuery=null;
        myQuery = "my query"
        // execute the query
        ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(myQuery); 
        // cycle through the resulSet and display what was grabbed
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
        //do something
        }
        resultSet.close();
        st.close();
        db2Conn.close();
    }
```

Comment: things are working fine, but i need help to make the db connection global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) consider db connection pooling see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/
b) if you do want to go for dbcp then create a singleton which will serve the connection to parts of the project.

Without knowing more about your project (single/multi user, web based), it hard to give more advice.

```
public static class SQL {

Connection connection = null;
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank";
String connectionUser = "admin";
String connectionPassword = "root";


public SQL(){}

public Connection getConnection () {

  if (connection != null) {
    return connection;
  }
  try{

  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
  return connection; 
 }
  catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
　return null;　　　
　}
  }
```

Comment: Its a normal Java Application and not web based, and for single user.

Comment: >> Its a normal Java Application and not web based, and for single user.  - It ain't normal then ;-)  Anyway, maybe moved your connection stuff to a static or singleton  class

Answer (score 0):

Thats how i do it but only for testingprojects:

```
public class SQL {

Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


public SQL(){

    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank";
    String connectionUser = "admin";
    String connectionPassword = "root";

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser,      connectionPassword);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And other classes extend the SQL class:

```
public class Kontostand extends SQL{

public String getKontostand(String kontoNr){

    String kontostand = "";

    try {

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM konten WHERE KontoNr = '" + kontoNr + "'");


        while(rs.next()){
            kontostand = rs.getString("Kontostand");
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return kontostand;  
}
```

But its just for my little projects within i practice web develepment...so i dont know if it works for bigger projects

Answer (score 0):

Keep all connection stuff in a static method and create connection object if it is null otherwise return existing connection object. If you want to go for global first option is static.